# the simplest function f(1)=-1; f(2)=0; f(3)=1; f(4)=0.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, rational-numbers

I'm looking for a function that gives

```
 f(1)=-1; f(2)=0; f(3)=1; f(4)=0.
```

The other values are undefined and I don't pay any attention on them.
The prefered functions are +, -, *, %, div and abs.  (the shorter function - the better).

It could be kind of sinus with period of 4, but sinus is not amonght the functions I asked above.
Needed for the programming to unite 4 cases into one (the first case we substract 1, the second and fourth we do nothing, for the third one we add one).

Thank you.

Comment: Very often, the following approach is used on such questions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial
These are easy to program - they see heavy use in numerical analysis and that is where I (and most other people) know them from in fact. This generalizes this kind of question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following: $$-|x-3|+1$$

An easy sine function should also work:$$-\sin(\frac{5x}{\pi})$$

Comment: Thank you for −|x−3|+1. That's exactly what I need - the easiest among the other answers. So, you were able to use the function of a*|x-b|+c. How were you sure there is such a function? Just curios, no answer is requested. I accept your answer as the best one for my purposes. Thank you.

Comment: @Haradzieniec: Glad you like my answer. The numbers $-1,0,1,0$ remind me of the function $|x|$. Then if you do some translations and rotations, i.e., $|x-b|+c$, you get what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Make the ansatz $f(x) = (x-2)(x-4)(ax+b),\;$ this trivially gives the zeroes at $x=2, x=4.\;$ Then you get for $x=1,3\;$ the equations $3a+3b=-1\;$ and $-3a-b = 1.\;$ Adding gives $b=0$ which implies $a=-1/3$.

Thus the function
$$f(x) = -\frac{1}{3}(x-2)(x-4)x$$ is a simple answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but −|x−3|+1 looks much simpler in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2 +cx+d$?