# Build the function by its values. Only combination of +, -, *, abs() allowed for this function.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers, rational-functions

I've decided to open a new, more common question about [the simplest function f(1)=-1; f(2)=0; f(3)=1; f(4)=0.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644877/).

So, here is the question. Let's say we have some function $y=f(x)$ we'd like to find by its values and some restrictions:

- we have pairs `(x0,y0), (x1,y1), .., (xn, yn)`.
- we want to find the function `f` that goes through the points above, but
- it should be the combination of the functions +, -, * and several abs.

Is it possible for any pairs? What's the common formula then?

Thank you.

Example:
For the pairs $(-10, -3), (-5,-3), (0, 7), (25, 13)$ the function $f(x)= −|x−3| + 5 + |x+5|$ looks good (If I didn't make a typo).

P.S. The shorter function - the better.

Thank you.

**P.P.S. Please no polynomials. Only the sum of abs of the |ai*xi+bi|.**

Comment: Are rational multipliers allowed in front of the abs? Like $(3/4)|x-2|+(1/4)|x-8|$? [Or would that be regarded as using division for the fractions?]

Comment: Yes, they are allowed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allow arbitrary numbers appear as coefficients, then the answer is yes.
WOLOG, assume your pairs are given in sorted order of $x_i$. i.e.

$$x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_n.$$
Let $\theta(x)$ be the function $|x| + x$ and define $f(x)$ as

$$\begin{align}
f(x) 
&= y_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{y_k-y_{k-1}}{2(x_k-x_{k-1})}\left(\theta(x-x_{k-1}) - \theta(x-x_{k})\right)\\
&= y_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{y_k-y_{k-1}}{2(x_k-x_{k-1})}\left(|x-x_{k-1}| - |x-x_{k}| + ( x_{k} - x_{k-1})\right)\\
&= \frac{y_0+y_n}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{y_k-y_{k-1}}{2(x_k-x_{k-1})}\left(|x-x_{k-1}| - |x-x_{k}|\right)
\end{align}$$
For any $0 < p < n$, we have

$$\begin{align}f(x_p) 
= & \frac{y_0+y_n}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^p \frac{y_k-y_{k-1}}{2(x_k-x_{k-1})}\left((x_p-x_{k-1}) - (x_p-x_{k})\right)\\
  &\hspace0.7in + \sum_{k=p+1}^n \frac{y_k-y_{k-1}}{2(x_k-x_{k-1})}\left((x_{k-1}-x_p) - (x_{k}-x_p)\right)\\
= &\frac{y_0+y_n}{2}
 + \sum_{k=1}^p \frac{y_k-y_{k-1}}{2(x_k-x_{k-1})}\left(x_k-x_{k-1}\right)
 + \sum_{k=p+1}^n \frac{y_k-y_{k-1}}{2(x_k-x_{k-1})}\left(x_{k-1}-x_{k}\right)\\
= &\frac{y_0+y_n}{2} + \frac{y_p - y_0}{2} + \frac{y_p - y_n}{2}\\
= & y_p
\end{align}$$
Similarly, one has $f(x_0) = y_0$ and $f(x_n) = y_n$. In short, $f(x)$ is a piecewise linear function passing through all the $(x_k,y_k)$.

Comment: I'm sorry I doubt f(x[k]) is equal to y[k].

It is f(x[k])=y[0]+0.5*sum_from_1_to_n(y[k]-y[k-1])=0.5*y[0]+0.5*y[n] <>y[k].

Comment: @Haradzieniec the slope for $\theta(x) = |x| + x$ is $2$ (instead of $1$ as your formula suggests) for positive $x$.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. In this case I get: f(x[k])=y[0]+sum_from_1_to_n(y[k]-y[k-1]). Right? That's y[n], not y[k].

Comment: @Haradzieniec that's not true, notice $|x| + x = 0$ for $x < 0$. For $k < n$, we have $$f(x_k) = y_0 + \sum_{p=1}^k\frac{y_p-y_{p-1}}{2(x_p-x_{p-1})}(2(x_p - x_{p-1})) + \sum_{p=k+1}^n\frac{y_p-y_{p-1}}{2(x_p-x_{p-1})}(0 - 0) = y_k.$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible if the $x_i$ are distinct, this is the classical interpolation problem. You can use polynomials, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial. I don't know any results for the `abs` case.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to use a polynomial, that's why I asked this question. Only the combination of abs of the first degree. Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: Then you should edit your question, polynomials obviously are compatible with the requirement `it should be the combination of the functions +, -, *`.

Comment: I edited the question already. I'm sorry for your time. Thank you. Just made it bold.